# How to Create a Gradient Border in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add a gradient border to a Container widget in Flutter, but I'm not sure how to achieve this effect since Flutter doesn't support gradient borders natively. I want the gradient to be applied to the border only, not the entire container. Could someone provide an example of how to create a gradient border around a Container or any other widget in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can put the container in a `DecoratedBox` and apply the gradient.

```
DecoratedBox(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
    
    // add gradient
    borderGradient: gradient 
  ),

  child: Container(),
),
```

Comment: This answer is misleading as `BoxDecoration` does not currently have a `borderGradient` property as of v3.13.9. See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html

Answer (score 0):

`gradient_borders: ^1.0.0` use this in pubspec.yaml

flutter pub get

```
Container(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: const GradientBoxBorder(
      gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red]),
      width: 4,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
  ),
),
```